# Keyboard close automatically and go back automatically when TextFormField is tapped in android

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Clone this application from github (dculussoftwares/vilvam.v2) and run it on android emulator.
2. Go to first search icon and try to hit the text editor on emulator.
3. Then this will automatically redirect to past page and close the keypad.
4. Try this on any text editor in the application

It is only happening on android platform only. IOS/Mac works smoothly

**Expected results**

Should open the keyboard and accept the input text.

**Actual results**

Keyboard close automatically and go back automatically

**Code sample**

Clone entire repo from github dculussoftwares/vilvam.v2 and it is public

**Flutter github link**

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/145262